# convert shell command "last" output to json

Tags: json, shell, jq

Is any option that i can convert shell `last` output to json

eg: last output

```
test   pts/0        1.1.1.1     Wed Jun 21 14:28 - 20:19  (05:51)
```

to

```
{
 name: "test",
 x1: "pts/0",
.
.
.
time: "(05:51)"
}
```

Comment: Your local operating system's implementation of `last` tab-separates the fields, right? Or are they space-separated, in which case we need to figure out which spaces are within a field and which separate fields?

Comment: Also note that you'll need to enforce a specific locale such that behavior like putting the day-of-week before the month is consistent.

Comment: You'll need to do it manually. Also, JSON requires that the keys are quoted too since they are supposed to be strings.

Comment: @glennjackman, what do you mean "manually"?

Comment: I meant (or intended to mean) that the OP needs to write some code.

Answer (score 2):

```
jq -R '
split("[[:space:]]+"; "g")
| select(length > 2) | select(.[0] != "")
| { "name":    (.[0]),
    "console": (.[1]),
    "ip":      (.[2]),
    "day":     (.[3])
  }
' < <(last)
```

Comment: thanks a lot that works!.. i want include all this timestamp under one field (( 'Mon Apr  9 15:31:32 2018 - Mon Apr  9 15:32:26 2018  (00:00)'  )) is that possible?

Comment: all the part next to 'ip' as one, also works...im trying this "timestamp": (.[3],.[4],......) that doesn't seem to be working any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider is using regex capture variables.  Consider for example:

```
capture("(?<name>^[^ ]+) +(?<token>[^ ]+) +(?<numeric>[0-9.]+) +(?<range>[^(]+)  +(?<time>.*)")
```

With the given input, i.e.:

```
test   pts/0        1.1.1.1     Wed Jun 21 14:28 - 20:19  (05:51)
```

the output would be:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "token": "pts/0",
  "numeric": "1.1.1.1",
  "range": "Wed Jun 21 14:28 - 20:19",
  "time": "(05:51)"
}
```